# How to search in a HTML table that does not generate any td's and such?

Tags: php, html, mysql, json, html-table

I've created a table based on the http://www.jtable.org template, my table, and most of the functionality is up and running, however I run into a problem when I want to include a search bar to filter tables results as I type. The problem I believe lies in the fact that most tables I've created using php have created the actual html table in the code so td's and tr's for example, and the search functionality  would key off of matching these terms.

Currently however my table is being generated on the front end, without the actual HTML content in the back end, so I am unable to search. Is there any method I can use to search this table with this code, maybe using server side processing, or something else I'm unaware of?

This is the code I'm using:

```
<html>
<title> title </title>
<head>

<link href="themes/redmond/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="scripts/jtable/themes/metro/darkgray/jtable.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script src="scripts/jquery-1.6.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="scripts/jtable/jquery.jtable.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>

<body>
   <div class="filtering">

<body>


<input type="text"  style="background-color: #e6ffff;" placeholder="Search  Any Column" size="70" id="search";/> 
</body>



<div id="PeopleTableContainer" style="width: relative;"  ></div>
<img src="Sharks-2-Trans-30-150623-2.png"  width="150" height="43"  style="float:bottom-right; opacity: 10;">



<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {

        //Prepare jTable
        $('#PeopleTableContainer').jtable({
            title: 'ICS Central',
            paging: true, //Enable paging
            pageSize: 10, //Set page size (default: 10)
            sorting: true, //Enable sorting
            defaultSorting: 'ISO_Name ASC', //Set default sorting
            selecting: true, //Enable selecting
            multiselect: true, //Allow multiple selecting
            selectingCheckboxes: true, //Show checkboxes on first column
            //selectOnRowClick: false, //Enable this to only select using checkboxes

            actions: {
                listAction: 'PersonActions2.php?action=list',
                createAction: 'PersonActions2.php?action=create', 

                updateAction: 'PersonActions2.php?action=update',
                deleteAction: 'PersonActions2.php?action=delete'
            },

            fields: {
                PersonId: {
                    key: true,
                    create: false,
                    edit: false,
                    list: false
                },
                ISO_Name: {
                    title: 'ISO Name',
                    width: '5%'
                },
                ICS_Defect: {
                    title: 'Defect #',

                    width: '5%'
                },
                Abstract: {
                    title: 'Abstract',

                    width: '30%'
                },
                problem_description: {
                    title: 'Problem Description',

                    width: '30%'
                },
                fix_description: {
                    title: 'Fix Description',

                    width: '30%'

                },

                 levels_approved: {
                    title: 'Levels Approved',

                    width: '30%'

                },
                reboot_required: {
                    title: 'Reboot Required?',

                    width: '30%'

                },
                 reapplied_after_ccl: {
                    title: 'Reapplied After CCL?',

                     width: '30%'

                },
                 reapplied_after_hmc_rebuild: {
                    title: 'Reapplied After HMC Rebuild?',

                    width: '30%'

                },
                 bundle_fix_cmvc: {
                    title: 'Bundle Fix CMVC',

                    width: '30%'

                }


            },




        //Register to selectionChanged event to hanlde events
        selectionChanged: function () {
            //Get all selected rows
            var $selectedRows = $('#PeopleTableContainer').jtable('selectedRows');

            $('#SelectedRowList').empty();
            if ($selectedRows.length > 0) {
                //Show selected rows
                $selectedRows.each(function () {
                    var record = $(this).data('record');
                    $('#SelectedRowList').append(
                        '<b>ISO_Name</b>: ' + record.ISO_Name +
                        '<br /><b>Abstract</b>:' + record.Abstract + '<br /><br />'
                        );
                });
            } else {
                //No rows selected
                $('#SelectedRowList').append('No row selected! Select rows to see here...');
            }
        },
       // rowInserted: function (event, data) {
         //   if (data.record.ISO_Name.indexOf('Add_Info_HB_v1.0.iso') >= 0) {
           //     $('#PeopleTableContainer').jtable('selectRows', data.row);
            //}
        //}
    });

    //Load student list from server
    $('#PeopleTableContainer').jtable('load');

    //Delete selected students
    $('#DeleteAllButton').button().click(function () {
        var $selectedRows = $('#PeopleTableContainer').jtable('selectedRows');
        $('#PeopleTableContainer').jtable('deleteRows', $selectedRows);
    });
});
</script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What will you do with the search?  Move the Jtable to that spot?  See if someone exists?

Comment: Essentially it would filter out any results that do not match the search term. Say I have 3 rows with different names "Mary" "Ann" "Lou", searching for "Lou" would only display any rows containing "Lou" . Hope this helps in clarifying my intentions

Comment: Any reason you don't just do a refresh on the table with the new search terms attached so the query doesn't return those items?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use a search text field and filter the result on keyUp, but that is not client side filtering. It makes the ajax call to the list action and uses a variable searchname to do its filtering. We use Hibernate and have a line of code that filters from the DB like: " obj.name like '%searchname%' "

```
<body>
   <div class="filtering">
      Name: <input type="text" id="search"/>
   </div>
<body>

...
...

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
       ...
       $('#search').keyup(function(){
          $('#PeopleTableContainer').jtable('load', {searchname: $(this).val()});
       });
    }
```

Comment: Was this what you where looking for?

Comment: Yes, I'm fairly new at coding, so I am still trying to get it to work, is there anything I have to add or change to your code?

Comment: no shouldn't need to change the code, just copy the filtering div into the body, and the $('#search').keyup(function(){
          $('#PeopleTableContainer').jtable('load', {searchname: $(this).val()});
       });
into the $(document).ready() function;

Comment: also adjusting you DB query to use the "like" clause

Comment: O that's it, I need a like clause statement, Thanks!